# TypeError: Cannot read property length from undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, if-statement, rhino

I am having two arrays of strings which may be undefined or defined with some value.

```
var a ; // [Array of strings]
var b ; // [Array of strings]
var c; // result array
```

I need to push some static value like "abc" in a third array like var c whenever either of the
array a or array b are defined and their length > 0. But my script is breaking , this is the line of code below.

```
if((typeof a !== 'undefined' ||typeof b !== 'undefined' ) && (a.length > 0 || b.length > 0) )
```

The above loc fails when I am assigning some value to 'a' and b is undefined. Error logs show me the below.

```
by: javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property \"length\" from undefined\n\tat
```

How can I change this condition to satisy my requirements.Is there a better away to achieve this.Also, I am using Rhino JS engine 1.13 ver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite it like

```
if((a !== undefined && a.length > 0) || (b !== undefined && b.length > 0)) {
  c = ...
}
```

To ensure you only check the length of each variable only if they are not undefined.

By the way, if you are using `'use strict'` mode, you can just use `a !== undefined` instead of `typeof a !== 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should group `a` tests then group `b` tests.

```js
if (
       typeof a !== "undefined" && a.length && a.length > 0
    || typeof b !== "undefined" && b.length && b.length > 0
) {
    c.push("abc");
}
```

And, as Rhino supports `Array.isArray()`, here is a smaller and cleaner code:

```js
if (Array.isArray(a) && a.length > 0 || Array.isArray(b) && b.length > 0) {
    c.push("abc");
}
```

Comment: In the first piece of code you need to use typeof or remove the quotes

Comment: Rhino definetly supports such code

Comment: Thanks for the info. Indeed [`isArray` is supported](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/f75125901ee1df681510200f63a6eb033342f488/src/org/mozilla/javascript/NativeArray.java#L2110-L2115) but, to comment on another solution, [optional chaining operator `.?` is not yet supported by Rhino.](https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/issues/937)

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see in your code is the first evaluation

```
(typeof a !== 'undefined' ||typeof b !== 'undefined' )
```

It returns true when either `a` or `b` is `'undefined'`.
For instance, imagine an instance where `a` is undefined but `b` is an array; `(typeof a !== 'undefined' ||typeof b !== 'undefined' )` evaluates to `true`.

The second evaluation which uses an **OR** (`||`) operation which starts from left to right;

```
(a.length > 0 || b.length > 0)
```

starts by evaluating

```
a.length
```

but `a` is `'undefined'` and hence the error.

I would use this

```
if((a !== undefined && a.length > 0) || (b !== undefined && b.length > 0)) {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can also check whether the value of the variable is null or undefined with the below way.

I guess this will help you. Try this:

```
if(a?.length > 0 && b?.length > 0){
    // Code here
}
```